# Plot a percentage from a decimal in Plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-python

I have a dataframe that I want to plot in a column chart. The dataframe shows percentages in decimal points (such as 0.9994400) and I would like to show them on my chart as 99.944%.

I've tried to change the axis of the chart multiple times, but the values always round up to 100%. How can I get the axis and hover numbers to show the decimal points?

For example, the first data point should show 99.944%, but it shows 100%.

*My dataframe: df_uptime_percentage*

| Name | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| API 1 | 0.9994400 |
| API 2 | 0.999914 |
| API 3 | 0.999913 |
| API 4 | 0.999925 |
| API 5 | 0.999461 |

*My plot script:*

```
cf.go_offline()

fig = df_uptime_percentage.iplot(kind='bar', 
        yTitle='Percent Uptime',
        xTitle='API Endpoint',
        asFigure = True)
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat = '%')
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")


fig.iplot()
```

*My plot output:*
[image]

*My imported libraries:*

```
import time
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import math
import requests
import re
import json
import pandas as pd 
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()
%matplotlib inline
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what is causing the numbers to be rounded, but if you add the y-axis tick marks to the percent table and add the number of digits, the axis will have two decimal places, and the hover text will also have two decimal places.

```
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *

cf.go_offline()

fig = df.iplot(kind='bar', 
        yTitle='Percent Uptime',
        xTitle='API Endpoint',
        asFigure=True)
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat='.3%')
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")

fig.iplot()
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfect, thank you! It seems so obvious now that you've shown your work.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't quite catch where in your code you imported the numbers from your data frame to be used for your plot, but from how you describe your issue, I'm thinking this has something to do with a floating-point error. I wrote some basic code to convert the value you got for API1:

```
x = 0.9994400
x = x*100
x = float("{:.2f}".format(x))

print(x)
```

This code prints `99.94`. If you were to change the 3rd line in the code to

```
x = float("{:.3f}".format(x))
```

it would give you `99.944`.

Hope this helps!